# ServerSocket not working when Java as Client and Android as server

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I want to make my android as Server and Java on PC as client.Is it possible?i tried but some error.I got server code from tutorial.

Note:I have connected my computer and phone on same router.

Server Code Android:

```
public class Server extends Activity {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    Handler updateConversationHandler;

    Thread serverThread = null;

    private TextView text;



    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        private BufferedReader input;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {


            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();

                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
        }

    }

}
```

Java Client code:

```
public class ServerCyb {

    public static void main(String[]arg) throws Exception
    {               
        Socket server1=new Socket("192.168.1.4", 6000);
        OutputStream e=server1.getOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(e);
        ps.println("Test");
        server1.close();
    }

}
```

Error on client:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ServerCyb.main(ServerCyb.java:20)
```

**EDITED:**
I have included all need permission on AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Anything from the server in logcat?  A permission problem should show there as socket creation will fail.

Comment: No error msg from logcat.Then i have included correct permission AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Add some logging of partial success.  Verify you have the correct IP address.  Try a client onboard the device...

Comment: I would say you get your anti virus off.It might block the connection.Also, if you are trying this from a phone and the server side is on your PC, don't forget to port-forward ,otherwise your localhost will be local ,not public.

Answer (score 1):

It may be an android permission problem. Check if this permision exists in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: i have included all permission on AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think the permissions for AndroidManifest.xml are -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `Socket server1=new Socket("192.168.1.4", 6000);` with

```
        server1 = new Socket();
        server1.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.4"),6000), 100);
```

Comment: Perhaps your firewall is blocking it. Make sure you allow in and out communication on that port in your firewall settings.

Comment: Wrong suggestion, this would make a client, not a server, and require other changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! :)

```
ServerSocket server;


try{
    String hostname = "yourIpAdress";
    server = new ServerSocket();
    server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port)); //you need this
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

while(true){
    try{
        Socket client = server.accept();
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        String messsage = input.readUTF();
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        output.writeUTF("Connected!");
        client.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You need this:

```
ServerSocket server;
String hostname = "yourIpAdress";
server = new ServerSocket();
server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port));
```